# Where can I find the questions I have starred?

Tags: support, profile-page, bookmarks

Above the **vote-up** and **vote-down** arrows, we can use the star icon to favorite a question. However, where can I access the list of my starred topics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find them in [your profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/current?tab=favorites) on the activities page.

On the mobile site, you must scroll down and change the drop down menu to favourites.